# How to shade a transitive dependency in Gradle?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, gradle, dependency-management

Is there a way to shadow a particular (transitive) dependency in Gradle? My situation: I have a project that depends directly on `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:1.10.33` and `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1`, but `hadoop-aws` in turns depends on `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:1.7.4` which screws the final JAR, but I need both anyway.

Is it currently possible to do something like this?

```
shadowJar {
    relocate('com.amazonaws', 'shadowedstuff.awsjdk') {
        include(dependency('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4'))
    }
}
```

Or a not-so-dirty workaround for it?

Thanks!

*NOTE*: shading the `aws-sdk` which my projects depends on directly is not an option. This is a simplification and in the original setup some reflection is going on.

Comment: What of you excluded `1.7.4` and only used `1.10.33` in both places?

Comment: My current solution is having `hadoop-aws` recompiled with `aws-java-sdk:1.10.33` and publishing it to my own repository in order to have only one `aws-java-jdk` in the fat jar . But then I cannot upgrade easily the `hadoop-aws` dependency and the idea itself doesn't scale to other use cases where shading a specific artifact would be great and simple, since some classes are used with reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [shadow](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow) plugin for Gradle to which has a [very similar syntax](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/#filtering-relocation) to your example:

```
// Configuring Filtering for Relocation
shadowJar {
   relocate('junit.textui', 'a') {
       exclude 'junit.textui.TestRunner'
   }
   relocate('junit.framework', 'b') {
       include 'junit.framework.Test*'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `resolutionStrategy` (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) to force a particular version.

Example from a projet:

```
configurations {
    testImplementation.extendsFrom compileOnly

    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Force jackson 2.4.4 for Spark
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.4'
            force 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-jre'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't shade the dependency, it just changes dependency resolution, which may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I've misunderstood your situation and it is in fact more complex but it looks like the exclusion can just be provided in the dependency declaration?

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-java-sdk'
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is precisely that I don't want to exclude any of the two versions (one is used directly and the other one is used by reflection), so I want to keep both, by shadowing one of them :)

Comment: shading will "alias" dependency for your code source only, to avoid conflict. Most of the time, you get conflict with "provided" library, so exclude will not work here.