# How to build and publish single JAR for multiple Gradle modules

Tags: java, gradle, publish

For the simplicity, this is the basic structure of my project:

```
root
|-- api
|   |-- src
|   `-- build.gradle (dependency on common)
|-- common
|   |-- src // (include common DTOs)
|   `-- build.gradle (dependency on some spring modules)
|-- sdk 
|   |-- src
|   `-- build.gradle  (dependency on common)
```

I want to publish the `sdk` module including the `common` sources:

This is what I tried:

1. Just building the `sdk` project creates a JAR containing only the `sdk` source expecting the `common` sources to be available on the class part when running.
2. I tried fat-jar (shadow-jar) but that included the Spring dependencies in it, while I would like to keep them out and only ref them in the POM file I publish to JFrog

What I'm trying to do is to build JAR for the `sdk` module that will include the sources of both `sdk` and `common` so I would be able to publish it to JFrog and allow my client to use it, and have access to the DTOs in common. Also the POM that is published with the JAR should include the dependencies in Spring as the `common` module depending on.

Is it possible?

Comment: Shadow JAR is probably the right direction, you can look into excluding dependencies here: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/dependencies/#filtering-dependencies

Comment: That worked for creating the JAR, but now when I publish to JFrog using the `maven-publish` plugin, the published POM is having no dependencies. While I want it to include the `common` spring dependencies. otherwise, who ever depend on the new JAR will have to include the spring dependencies manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use [shadowing](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104725/12473843

P.S. To fix issue with Maven-publish plugin not including dependencies into generated pom.xml file please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486292/12473843

Comment: That worked for creating the JAR, but now when I publish to JFrog using the `maven-publish` plugin, the published POM is having no dependencies. While I want it to include the `common` spring dependencies. otherwise, who ever depend on the new JAR will have to include the spring dependencies manually

Comment: @RoeeGavirel please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486292/12473843